# Footable pagination using server side

Tags: footable

I need to achieve the footable pagination server side. How do I get the page number and page size from footable?
How do I write an `onclick` page number event?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Don't hide footable pagination while sorting footable pagination was taking place.